# Kivy Color Wheel

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

I understand Kivy ships with a color picker (kivy.uix.colorpicker), which is great and all, but I **just want the wheel** - the color wheel. That's all I want to have show in a certain space. The entire other half of the layout I don't need. At all.

Using kivy's KV, ColorWheel as a widget shows absolutely nothing, but doesn't throw any errors. I'm really confused because it seems as though the wheel itself is a pretty standalone widget (looking at the documentation) and I have no idea why I can't see it.

Help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ColorWheel object needs to trigger its "init_wheel" method to display something. And this is not done in its "**init**" method.

You also need to edit the "on_hsv" method to listen at the color selection.

This class inherits from the ColorWheel object and changes it to make it autonomous:

```
from kivy.uix.colorpicker import ColorWheel

class AutonomousColorWheel(ColorWheel):
    def __init__(self, **kwarg):
        super(AutonomousColorWheel, self).__init__(**kwarg)
        self.init_wheel(dt = 0) 

    def on__hsv(self, instance, value):
        super(AutonomousColorWheel, self).on__hsv(instance, value)
        print(self.rgba)     #Or any method you want to trigger
```

Hope it helps.